# Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease 500 Internal Server Error [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]

Tags: apt, php, ppa

I'm trying to install PHP8 along with the PHP7 in my system,
using this [LINK](https://help.clouding.io/hc/en-us/articles/360021630059-How-to-Install-Multiple-PHP-Versions-7-2-7-4-8-0-and-8-1-on-Ubuntu-20-04)

but when I run the below command

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

I get error something like this,

```
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-qa/ubuntu focal InRelease
  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Hit:9 https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:10 https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:11 https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:12 https://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-qa/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  500  Internal Server Error [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Have you tried again a few minutes later?

Comment: i have tried many times, but not working